# Creating permissions with laravel authorty

Tags: authorization, acl, laravel, user-permissions

I want to integerate Laravel Authority bundle in my laravel application.

How can i implement ACL for it?

My approach is like every controller will define permissions associated with the controller. Then I will map those permissions with roles. The Authority initialization will load the permissions available for the session user and pass them to authority. Permissions can be later on checked normally with Authority::can().

Now my question is how can I load all the permissions available in the controllers at some page which will allow me to set permissions to roles.

Is it the right way to define permissions?

Please help.

Comment: Are you one laravel3 or laravel4?

Comment: @AlbinN - It was L3 but now I am on L4.

Comment: Bundles doesnt work for L4. You should check out the package Entrust. I use it for user roles and permissions. https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments bundles do not work with laravel 4 but Matt Machugas [Authority](https://github.com/machuga/authority-l4) package for laravel-4 seems to suit your needs exactly.  It allows you create roles with certain prividleges and then add individual permissions to on top or instead of those roles if you want, I find it very easy to use.

Comment: Do you have a good tutorial for this package? I find the documentation to be lacking. While it covers the functions of the package, it leaves a lot out.

Comment: No Sorry I just had to mess around with it.  It actually turned out to be fairly straightforward but initially I was overwhelmed as well.  I think this is machugas project and he is in irc a lot and didnt mind answering my questions